# Finding extrema under boundary constraint

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to find the local extrema of the function $$f(x,y) = 4x^2-3xy$$ in the constraint
$$M = \left\{  (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 ≤ 1 \right\}$$

I plotted the function and the constraint and was able to see that the extrema are on the constraint itself. Is there a way  to prove that all the extrema of f in M are in this subset? $$ N= \left\{  (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 = 1 \right\} \subset M$$If not how can I find the  extrema in a boundary constraint?

Comment: Do you know Kuhn Tucker method? Given inequality condition, that would be one of the approaches. Lagrange equation gives a few critical points to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the only critical point of $f$ is $(0,0)$ and that it's a saddle point.  Now use the $N$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,s) = f(x,y)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-1+s^2)
$$

where $f(x,y) = 4x^2-3xy$ and $s$ is a slack variable transforming a inequality into an equivalent equation.

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \cases{8x-3y+2\lambda x = 0\\ -3y+2\lambda y = 0\\ x^2+y^2-1+s^2 = 0\\ \lambda s = 0
}
$$

with solutions

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc} 
f & x & y & \lambda & s^2 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{9}{2} & -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & -\frac{9}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{9}{2} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & -\frac{9}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The solutions with $s=0$ are located at the  boundary. The solution for $s=\pm 1$ is internal to the boundary and it is not a minima or maxima as can be observed on the associated $f$ values.